# Naming convention in config.xml

Tags: module, configuration

I'm on Magento 1.9.2 and following these [tutorials to learn Magento](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-5.html). On this page there are instructions to create a Module for loading blog posts. I followed the instructions to the point until this piece of code

```
public function testModelAction() {
        $blogpost = Mage::getModel('weblog/blogpost');
        echo get_class($blogpost);
}
```

where i was supposed to get this error:

```
include(Magentotutorial/Weblog/Model/Blogpost.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Instead I got this

```
include(Mage/Weblog/Model/Blogpost.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Notice the path starts from `Mage` and not `Magentotutorial`. I triple checked everything on the tutorial to make sure everything was exactly as they asked and it was.

After several minutes of searching I tried changing `Magentotutorial_Weblog` to `Magentotutorial_weblog` in the `Magentotutorial/Weblog/etc/config.xml` and the error resolved itself.

```
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_Weblog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Magentotutorial_Weblog>
    </modules>
    ...
```

I'm not able to understand why. I've used capital W everywhere else (Module names, directory names, global config file). The tutorial didn't mention the use of small letter here so I would appreciate if someone could explain why this is the case.

Complete XML file is here:

```
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_weblog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Magentotutorial_weblog>
    </modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <weblog>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Magentotutorial_Weblog</module>
                <frontName>weblog</frontName>
            </args>
        </weblog>
    </routers>
</frontend>
<global>

    <models>
        <weblog>
            <class>Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model</class>
            <!--
            need to create our own resource, can't just
            use core_resource
            -->
            <resourceModel>weblog_resource</resourceModel>
        </weblog>
        <weblog_resource>
            <class>Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <blogpost>
                    <table>blog_posts</table>
                </blogpost>
            </entities>
        </weblog_resource>
    </models>
</global>
</config>
```

Comment: Can you post your config.xml here?

Comment: Done. Please check